# ambari + how to disable new datanode machine from data replication

Tags: hdfs, ambari, hdp, datanode

we have ambari and HDP 2.6.4 cluster with 245 workers machines

each worker have ( datanode component and resource manager component )

now we want to add 10 new workers machines to the cluster

but we want to disable the datanode machines so no HDFS data will transfer from the old datanodes to the new datanodes

I thinking to set maintenance mode on the new datanode ,

but not sure if this action is enough in order to disable the new datanodes machine on the new workers

so the target is to avoid replication of HDFS data from the old datanode to the new datanode

I will happy to get any advice about this

Comment: You can decommission your newly created data nodes, check [this](http://www.hadooplessons.info/2017/12/decommissioning-datanodes-hadoop-cluster-hdpca.html)

Comment: I try it but decommission not succeeded , what you say about just to stop the datanode service?

Comment: Only Stopping Datanodes will not cause a problem If they have only data node service in it. will you please edit your question with difficulties you got while decommissioning data nodes? because I've never encountered that problem (decommission not succeeded).

Comment: Will you please Update this question?